# Add bookmarks to bookmarks bar via policy

Tags: ios, google-chrome, bookmarks, mdm

I am capable of adding bookmarks to a "managed bookmarks" folder with the following code and deploy that via a policy.  But to make things easier on the younger students, I would like to deploy bookmarks instead to the bookmarks bar.

```
<key>BookmarkBar</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>Google HomePage</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://www.google.com</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict> 
    <key>BookmarkBarEnabled</key>
        <true/>
```

How can this be done?